# Bangkok Ekamai to Koh Chang

Tags: buses, thailand, bangkok

What is the best bus from Ekamai Bangkok for Travellers to Koh Chang. Is there a service directly to the piers?

The internet information is a little unclear about the last portion of the trip.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [government bus timetable](http://home.transport.co.th/en/bus-schedule/442-central-and-east-route.html)
you can take a bus direct to the pier at Laem Ngop from Ekamai at 6:30, 7:45 and 9:45. Then you take the ferry, and a taxi on Koh Chang to your resort.

Comment: I take it that the bus is 1                               917-1  กรุงเทพฯ - แหลมงอบ  Bkk - Lamngob